# adding a class to the <Li> tag using jquery when click on li which is inside iframe window is not appling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

The Iframe i designed in one of the aspx page

```
<iframe id="iFrameWindow" runat="server" src="IdentifierDensity.aspx" height="620px" width="98%"
                                        style="margin-left: 1%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This part of below code which is in the above aspx page i given as a source for the iframe

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">

              <p class="centered"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/dashboard_2.png" class="img-circle" width="60"></a></p>

              <li class="sub-menu" id="sub-menu">
                  <a href="javascript:;" class="dcjq-parent active">
                      <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                      <span>Dashboard Reports</span>

                  </a>
                  <ul class="sub" id="submenu">
                      <li id="IdentifierDensity"><a href="IdentifierDensity.aspx"><asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
                      <li id="MatchScore"><a href="MatchScore.aspx"><asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
                      <li id="IdenticalTestcase"><a href="IdenticalTestcase.aspx"><asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
```

the following jquery i used to set the class is as below

```
 $("#submenu li").click(function () {
            alert(this.id);
            $("ul.submenu li#" + this.id).addClass('active');
        });
```

If the run the application , in the inspect element i can able to see the class assigned for the li.

but the iframe is not allowing to applying the class i think so.

help me on this.

Comment: *but the iframe is not allowing to applying the class i think so.*  | `not allowing` = `not allowing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?

`$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: I added this , and the class is added but page is getting refreshed , so the class added to the li tag gone.

Comment: if you're trying to add the class to elements in the iframe, use `$('#iFrameWindow').contents()` to target elements inside of the iframe.